# how to call specific function from outside an application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

Ok so I have a C# program which handles some scheduled tasks. However I need to be able to call a specific function within this program from windows task scheduler.

I have no code or no starting points because frankly I don't even know the proper terminology to put into a google search... its like I am trying to search for "ferrari" by typing in "things with disk shaped objects mounted on the sides". I just have no idea where to even start. I need someone to just give me a quick brief on where I should be looking to accomplish this task. Once I know where to look I can figure it out.

Heres what I need to do.

I have a c# winforms application that has several functions inside of it (lets say method_1, method_2, and method_3). I want to create a windows scheduled task that runs just method_2. I was imagining some sort of launch parameter like you can put in the "target" line of shortcuts like "chrome.exe /d" or whatever.

Thoughts? I am probably over thinking things honestly, but some simple suggestions would be nice.

Comment: Are you looking for network related "stuffs", like Windows Communication Foundation(WCF)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @butterbox nah its a winforms desktop application.

Comment: So you wish to not use network or pipebinding? Then I don't know, maybee create a dll? (class library) and place your function there?

Comment: @butterbox how would one call a function that is inside a class library .dll file from a scheduled task? Is it possible to have multiple .exe's inside my winforms application? One main version and one cut down version that only does the basics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to dcastro I like to add that you could also create a library and create several dedicated executables to call specific functions inside this library

Then also use this library from your winforms app.

Projects in your solution:

- library.dll with all the shared methods
- Task1.exe: Exe to be called from the scheduled Task. (References library.dll)
- WinFormApp.exe: Your gui (References library.dll)

Comment: thats just what I suggested above! :D So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: I marked this as the answer since it is the way I will be going! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unusual to have a windows scheduled task executing a winforms app... scheduled tasks are more commonly used to execute background tasks/services. It's a little hard to give you further advice without knowing more about what you're trying to do.

Usually, you'd move the common logic to its own assembly and compile it as a Class Library.
Then you'd have your WinForms project reference the shared class library, a third project for your scheduled task that also uses the class library.

---

But if want to send parameters to your WinForms app, you could change your `Program.Main` signature from this:

```
static void Main()
```

to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

The `args` array will contain the arguments passed to your application. You can interpret these and call the appropriate method.

Comment: Thats exactly why I only want to call the specific function... the winforms app does a lot which requires a gui. But one of the functions is something I need to be able to trigger both with a button push and through a scheduled task so it needs to be available to the form... but also outside the form.

Comment: It could go this way, mylibrary.dll (holds all the common classes, functions), then form.exe and task.exe (both which import the same library). Form.exe is my winform app and task.exe is the script I want the windows scheduled task to run. However how does one create two .exe's within the same visual studio project?

Comment: @JoW. What I would do is: Move the common logic to its own assembly, and compile it as a class library. Then, the winforms can import that assembly and call its methods. Then create another [Tasks Scheduled Managed Wrapper](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) project that also uses the shared class library, and that provides an entry point for the scheduled task to call your method.

Comment: @JoW. Exactly. Too create two exes, just add more projects to the solution. When you compile the solution, each project will produce its output. You'd have to have 3 projects: 1 Winforms App, 1 shared Class Library and 1 Scheduled Task.

Comment: Oh wow here's me not even knowing there is a difference between a project and a solution >_< lol ... thanks guys!!! Just what I needed to know :D

Comment: @JoW. I confess I was also confused when I began using Visual Studio, coming from Eclipse :) I'll update my answer with the advice in the comments.